# Could these PHP calls be from Android iPhone devices?

Tags: php

I have some PHP scripts that should ONLY really be getting called by Android or iPhone devices. My script checked the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] value.

Normally an Android device results in something like this...
[22-Mar-2017 14:39:21 UTC] * USER AGENTS Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-G531BT Build/LMY48B)

An iPhone seems to create something like this...
[22-Mar-2017 14:39:23 UTC] * USER AGENTS txlfree/182 CFNetwork/808.3 Darwin/16.3.0

I don't want ANY browser queries to these scripts, just phone queries.

am thinking of just blocking calls that DON'T contain ANDROID or CFNETWORK in the HTTP_USER_AGENT value.

Any problems that could arise here? Could I block genuine php calls from Android and iPhone if I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't rely on browser detection only by the user agent string. You can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent) why this is no good idea. Furthermore, the user agent string can be modified in any way. You need some other kind of authentication.

Comment: I have two password that are passed in by the apps to the PHP scripts. This is then checked in the script. However, I know that these could be intercepted and used by other calls.

Comment: Can you recommend any other way to try to reduce the chance of someone returning data from my PHP scripts using just a browser etc.

Comment: https://github.com/sinergi/php-browser-detector

Comment: It seems that there is no perfect solution for this problem. A discussion of apropriate means to protect a webservice [can be found here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/42586), but surely there is no easy way to protect your backend from unauthorized requests. Relying on the user agent could only be a weak part of protecting the service.